# How do I detect the wanted change on a dynamic page controlled by JS?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, javascript, selenium

If I disable JS, the page doesn't work.

There's a form to choose a date. After you click the form, two tables appear. These tables are created by JS and they just show two months. You can click left or right to change the dates tables show. If you click right a dozen times, you start seeing available dates. All of these actions are controlled by JS.

Sometimes someone cancels their appointment so a new available date opens up in next 4 months. I want to be notified as soon as that happens.

I can do all of that if this page didn't use JS to display content details. I don't know enough JS to know how to proceed. I currently use inspect element and I can see the HTML code which was displayed by the JS.

How can I "click" buttons on the page programmatically?

Should I create a chrome extension for myself to figure out what's going on on the page?

How should I proceed?

Please help. This is really important to me